# Pinch in zoom in android

Tags: android

In My layout 
parent as Relative layout and then am having Scroll view
inside Linear layout 
now am having child views as Image view Text View Web view and Recycle view and 2 buttons is there
now i want to pinch in zoom entire layout

please help me out
Regards
Govardhana

Comment: I don't think your problem belongs in a SE board dedicated to video game development.

Comment: This question is not very clear to be at the moment. Can you please edit it to explain your current setup in more detail, what you've tried so far, and how the results of those attempts differ from the behaviour that you want?